# 'receptionist' & 'deceptionist'

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, antonyms

If a *receptionist* is a person who greets and deals with visitors to a office, can *deceptionist* be an acceptable English word to describe a person who delays and blocks visitors to a office, especially one who impedes visitors meeting the boss?

Or is there a better word?

Comment: Sounds like an excellent choice to me, witty even.

Comment: No, because delaying and blocking visitors are not deceptions.

Comment: @Oldcat I think it's implicit that there's some deception if the receptionist is deliberately delaying people (as opposed to merely informing them of a genuine delay).

Comment: @Oldcat Also, portmanteaus don't always perfectly fit the definitions of both words they're made up of. I'd excuse it in this case, at least, because of the witty rhyme.

Comment: You could ask if the expressions *deceive* and *receive* are related to one another, and what would be the opposite of someone who receives (a receptionist). I quite like your question, it's quirky!

Comment: It's a clever coinage, but indicates that the receptionist is lying. If that's what you want to express, go for it.

Comment: Elberich Schneider, I haven't heard of it or been able to find it in a dictionary. It seems like it should be a word for someone involved in some kind of **deception** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/deception?q=deception

Answer (score 3):

Of course a receptionist will often also be responsible for turning away those attempting to see the "boss" sometimes by redirecting to more appropriate members of staff and sometimes by insisting that the person that they wish to see is absent or otherwise engaged.

A deceptionist would to me suggest someone who attempts to deceive - some better words for one who tries to deflect visitors might include: Guardian, Gatekeeper, Cerberus, Filter, Deflector.